# @vercel/og api route isn't displaying correct image

Tags: javascript, next.js, facebook-opengraph, vercel

I have my nextjs app hosted on vercel edge, and I am trying to configure the vercel/og package: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/og-image-generation

When I load the api route /api/og on the application it simply shows a blank image, but it should contain some basic text.

```
// /pages/api/og.js
import { ImageResponse } from '@vercel/og'


export const config = {
  runtime: 'experimental-edge',
};

export const handler = (request) => {

  return new ImageResponse(
    (
      <div>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>,
      {
        width: 1200,
        height: 630
      }
    )
  );
};

export default handler;
```

It may be related to how I am passing the url to the metatag, but from what I can see it is correct.

```
const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST;

<meta property='og:image' content={`${baseUrl}/api/og`} />
```

I have configured the environment variables on vercel so that the value of NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST is the domain of the website, excluding the trailing /. Based on the docs this is all I need to do. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Nope, I can go to the api route in the browser and it shows fine

Comment: You have a typo, the closing `)` should be after `</div>`, not after the object, e.g. `new ImageResponse((<div><p>test</p></div>), { width: 1200, height: 630 });`. The `ImageResponse` constructor accepts two parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it appears that providing a width and height property prevents this from working.

Answer (score 0):

The outer `<div>` by default only has a transparent background, you need to give a basic style to make it work:

```js
style={{
  display: 'flex',
  background: 'white',
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
}}
```